# Mongodb: how can i generate all days base on current month

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering if anyone has an elegant solution for generating days based on a month selected for use in a dropdown. What i'm wanting to do is for the user to select the month, then populate a dropdown for days for that month. So for example if the user selected january you would have a dropdown list with values 1 - 31. The only bit i think might be tricky will be to do with leap years, so it may need to pass in year as well. Any ideas would be most appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

for calendar and get day of month use '[moment](https://momentjs.com/)'

```
moment("2012-02", "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth() // 29
moment("2012-01", "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth() // 31
```